# clicking on particular link using qtp function

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I want to automate login process to flipkart by creating a function which is being called in an action

```
Function Website() 'this is the function
Systemutil.Run("iexplore.exe"), "http://www.flipkart.com" 
End Function
```

`Website(`) 'this is where the function is called in the action

The browser is opening but I don't know how to click on login without doing a record and run , but only through code and the function.

Please help me.

Comment: Do you intend to work with the object repository or with descriptive programming?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it with descriptive programming, this would be a simple example:
(I used the direct login-page, because it is easier than clicking on that login link)

```
Website()

Function Website()
    Systemutil.Run("iexplore.exe"), "https://www.flipkart.com/account/login?from=header"
    set objPage = Browser("title:=Flipkart.com: Login.*").Page("title:=Flipkart.com: Login.*")

    objPage.Sync()

    objPage.WebEdit("html id:=login_email_id1").Set "UsernameXY"
    objPage.WebEdit("html id:=login_password1").Set "SecretPassword"
    objPage.WebButton("html id:=login-cta").Click()

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose two approaches from here.
1. Object Repository: Press Ctrl + R to Open object repository. Then add objects to your repository. Once you add them, Just Drag and drop.

2. Descriptive Programming: Just Like answer one